# C# how to transact Entity Framework and ADO.NET at a time

Tags: c#

I have a parent-child data windows form. My parent data is fetched by an entity class created with Entity Framework.

But my child datagridview datasource is bound with a datatable with multiply data table query from my database.

So I use Entity Framework to insert or update the ‘parent’ data, and I use ADO.NET to create and update the ‘child’ data records.

When I insert child data I have to get the Id of parent data as foreign key.

In this setup, how can I have a transaction over both?
Just simply use `TransactionScope`?

Comment: Use same DB connection and enable transaction on that object or create multiple connections and attach same transaction object. In general transactions are bad design ideab here, let everything be part of same operation be and idea DB implicit transaction, where all goes or nothing that's far better in such cases

Answer (score 1):

```
//Simpy use TransactionScope can solve this problem. 
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            tblOrder tblOrder = new tblOrder() { FOrderNum = "12345", FOrderType = "OrderTYpe", FClientID = 1086, FOrderStatus = "ReadyToProduction" };
            EFContext context = new EFContext();

            context.tblOrders.Add(tblOrder);
            context.SaveChanges();
            scope.Dispose();
            int orderID = tblOrder.FOrderID;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("****");
            string sql = $"INSERT INTO tblOrderSub (FOrderID,FMaterialID,FQty,FQtyShip,FFinishSKU,FModelCust,FColorCust)" +
                                    $" VALUES(@FOrderID,@FMaterialID,@FQty,@FQtyShip,@FFinishSKU,@FModelCust,@FColorCust)";
            SqlParameter[] sqlParameters =
                {
                    new SqlParameter("@FOrderID",orderID),
                    new SqlParameter("@FMaterialID",1),
                    new SqlParameter("@FQty",1),
                    new SqlParameter("@FQtyShip",1),
                    new SqlParameter("@FFinishSKU",false),
                    new SqlParameter("@FModelCust", "TEst"),
                    new SqlParameter("@FColorCust", "C1")
                };
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            scope.Complete();
        }
```

Comment: This may work but in general distributed transactions with multiple resources like collection are always a bad idea, always try and use implicit transaction